# Wordpress AJAX JavaScript Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm currently transferring a site from Drupal to WordPress and I'm running into an issue with a page that uses the AJAX. I notice that the user relied solely on a [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com) on how to implement AJAX using JavaScript, PHP and MySQL. On Drupal, AJAX is working perfectly fine but the WordPress version is not. I've been searching around the net and StackOverflow. There are apparently many plugins being used which I will consider but to make this quick I hope the current code works without the plugins. I also installed the allow php so I'm able to run scripts in php to start out but nothing else is working.

WordPress Header File:

```
<script>
function change() {
    var height = document.getElementById("fheight").value;
    var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").checked;
    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").checked;
    var basketball = document.getElementById("basketball").checked;
    var soccer = document.getElementById("soccer").checked;
    var football = document.getElementById("football").checked;
    var baseball = document.getElementById("baseball").checked;
    var volleyball = document.getElementById("volleyball").checked;
    var letter = document.getElementById("letter").value;
    var male = document.getElementById("male").checked;
    var female = document.getElementById("female").checked;



    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("recruitsearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}
}xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.protectingurl.com/php/search.php?height="+height+"&lastname=" + lastname + "&firstname=" + firstname + "&basketball=" + basketball + "&baseball=" + baseball + "&football=" + football +"&soccer=" + soccer + "&volleyball=" + volleyball + "&letter=" + letter + "&male=" + male + "&female=" + female , true);
xmlhttp.send();


}
</script>
```

WordPress page HTML:

```
<div id="ftitle">
<strong>Filter</strong>
</div>



 <div id="inheight">

</div>
<div id="sport">
<form action="" >
<label>Height</label>
<select  id="fheight">
<option>All</option>
<option>5' 0"</option>
<option>5' 1"</option>
<option>5' 2"</option>
<option>5' 3"</option>
<option>5' 4"</option>
<option>5' 5"</option>
<option>5' 6"</option>
<option>5' 7"</option>
<option>5' 8"</option>
<option>5' 9"</option>
<option>5' 10"</option>
<option>5' 11"</option>
<option>6' 0"</option>
</select>
<label>Sport</label>
   <input   type="checkbox" id="basketball" value="Basketball" />Basketball<input  type="checkbox" id="soccer" value="Soccer" />Soccer<input type="checkbox"  id="baseball" value="Baseball" />Baseball  <input  type="checkbox" id="softball" value="Softball" /> Softball <input type="checkbox"  id="volleyball" value="Volleyball" />Volleyball<input type="checkbox"  id="football"  value="Football"/>Football          
   <label>Choose a letter to search</label>
   <select  id="letter">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
<option>E</option>
<option>F</option>
<option>G</option>
<option>H</option>
<option>I</option>
<option>J</option>
<option>K</option>
<option>L</option>
<option>M</option>
<option>N</option>
<option>O</option>
<option>P</option>
<option>Q</option>
<option>R</option>
<option>S</option>
<option>T</option>
<option>U</option>
<option>V</option>
<option>W</option>
<option>X</option>
<option>Y</option>
<option>Z</option>
</select><input  type="checkbox"  value="firstname" id="firstname" />First Name<input type="checkbox"  value="lastname" id="lastname" />Last Name
 <label>Gender</label>
 <input  type="checkbox"id="male" />Male<input  type="checkbox" id="female"/>Female 

 </form>
</div>

<button onclick="change()">Search</button>

<div id="recruitsearch" class="scroll">
[php function=1]
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">          $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#myTable").tablesorter();
      }
 ); </script>
```

I've tested the php page numerous time and its working correctly. If I need to use a plugin or missing something all this information will be a great help.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127557/loading-database-content-via-xmlhttprequest-in-wordpress/16128067#16128067).

Comment: @RCV 
So adding the add_action to my php file is the best option?

Comment: Also, pass the `action` through `ajax` request. Check the example properly.

Comment: Check my answer. This is what I've tried and its not working. Let me know if the syntax is off.

Answer (score 0):

So I went into the theme functions.php of my theme and added this.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_databaseAjax', 'databaseAjax' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_databaseAjax', 'databaseAjax' );
```

In my Javascript, I've edited the end of the code to look like this.

```
var data = "action=databaseAjax&height="+ height+"&lastname=" + lastname + "&firstname=" + firstname + "&basketball=" + basketball + "&baseball=" + baseball + "&football=" + football +"&soccer=" + soccer + "&volleyball=" + volleyball + "&letter=" + letter + "&male=" + male + "&female=" + female;
```

xmlhttp.open("POST","http://myurl.com/wordpresstest/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" , true);
xmlhttp.send(data);

I'm posting this to make sure I'm doing everything right. I've looked into the admin-ajax file and see that it looks for wp_ajax_nopriv_ and wp_ajax_ .

Comment: There was a syntax error. Right now its not picking up my databaseAjax function. Any help?

Comment: I'm only getting 0 now. sigh.

Comment: Apparently in the URL I had a extra letter that solved the problem for me but now I'm running into another issue with table sorter.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the mix up. There was an extra letter in the URL that caused everything to go south.

It happen when I brought this line of code over.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.protectingurl.com/php/search.php?height="+height+"&lastname=" + lastname + "&firstname=" + firstname + "&basketball=" + basketball + "&baseball=" + baseball + "&football=" + football +"&soccer=" + soccer + "&volleyball=" + volleyball + "&letter=" + letter + "&male=" + male + "&female=" + female , true);
```

I'm researching the other issue when I'm going to to use the update trigger for table sorter in hopes that it will work correctly after updating table data.